# Find two complex roots of quadratic given it's square roots

Tags: complex-numbers

a: find square roots of $-3+4i,$

for which I got: $-1-2i,$ and $1+2i$

b: Find two complex roots of the quadratic equation $z^2 + 2(1+i)z + 3 - 2i =0.$

Had a few attempts Eg. the sum of roots but I am very confused.

Comment: Welcome at MSE. What exactly is your question? Where did you get stuck? BTW you can use LaTeX/Mathjax to typeset equations on MSE.

Comment: These questions are separate, use the quadratic formula

Comment: Not entirely separate. When you use the quadratic formula, you will find that the determinant happens to be similar to the number from the first part of the question.

Comment: Tried this - I cannot do it - Maybe I am making a mistake. Got to -1 -i +/- Root 12i -12

Answer (score 0):

Use the quadratic formula exactly as you did with *usual*, real equations:

$$\Delta=\left[2(1+i)\right]^2-4\cdot1\cdot(3-2i)=8i-12+8i=4(-3+4i)$$

so the roots are

$$z_{1,2}=\frac{-2(1+i)\pm\sqrt\Delta}2$$

And you know the roots square roots of $\;\Delta\;$...

Comment: So I say -1 -1 +/- Root (4(-3+4i)) - Then what?

Comment: @boiShift Then nothing: $\;z_{1,2}\;$ **are the equation's roots** ...! What else do you want?

Comment: The question requires the two complex roots: Answers are: i and 2-3i

Comment: @boiShift Well, I get $\;i\,,\,\,-2-3i\;$ , but yes: these are the roots...so??

Comment: How do I get to that final part - and yes you are right it's i2-3i. That is the final answer i need.

Comment: @boiShift Use what you did in part (a) !! Then you have that $$z_{1,2}=-(1+i)\pm(1+2i)=\begin{cases}\;\;\;\;\;i\\-2-3i\end{cases}$$ ...you just *have to write explicitly* the square roots of $\;\Delta\;$ , that's all.

Comment: I see, thank you. I was confused about which square root to use - Does it not matter, will I get the same result each way?

Comment: @boiShift There are **always** two square roots for any non-zero complex number, and they differ *only* by their sign. As you have $\;\pm\sqrt\Delta\;$ in the roots' formula, you get to use both and you lose nothing.

Answer (score 0):

For b just use the quadratic formula. You should find the discriminant is $-12+16i$, four times the quantity you square-rooted in a.

Comment: So I say -1 -1 +/- Root (4(-3+4i)) - Then what?